# Adding user to group within Active Directory

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add a user to a group using the below code. This works fine when running on a Windows 8 machine but not for a Windows 7 or when run locally on the server.

```
Dim userContext As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, userDistinguishedName)
Dim groupContext As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, groupDistinguishedName)

Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(userContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName)
Dim group As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(groupContext, groupName)
group.Members.Add(user)
group.Save()
```

The variables look like:

```
samAccountName: qwerty
groupName: Domain Guests
domainName: testdomain
userDistinguishedName: OU=Staff Member Accounts,OU=Domain Accounts,OU=Domain Objects,DC=testdomain,DC=local
groupDistinguishedName: CN=Users,DC=testdomain,DC=local
```

The error is:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: pricipal
 at
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalCollection.add(Principal Principal)
 at
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalCollection.add(User Principal User)
 at
Add_New_User_Module.addNewUserToGroup(String samAccountName, String groupName, String domainName, String userDistinguishedName, String groupDistinguishedName)
```

Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you check that user was empty or that it found principal?